# pipe '|' doesn't seem to be liked on my ansible script

Tags: shell, ansible

I have a task to count how many files exist. Is there something wrong with the syntax?

```
task:
- name: "Getting Local File Count"
  kubernetes.core.k8s_exec:
    namespace: "{{namespace}}"
    pod: "{{pod}}"
    command: "find '{{local_dir}}' -type f | wc -l"
  register: command_status
```

but after executing the playbook I get

> "find: paths must precede expression: |",

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common mistake coming from a world of `CMD` in docker, which has two forms: free text and `exec` -- but in kubernetes descriptors, it's **always** the `exec` form. If one wishes to have shell helpers, such as pipes or `&&` or functions or redirection, one must do that explicitly via `sh -c` style constructs

The bad news is that the ansible module's `command:` argument doesn't accept a `list[str]` and instead they choose to use [`shlex.split`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.kubernetes/blob/1.2.1/plugins/modules/k8s_exec.py#L170) so you have to either copy the complicated command into the pod and just use `command: /path/to/my/script.sh` or take your chances with `shlex`, which *seems* to understand `sh -c` quoting:

```py
>>> shlex.split("""sh -c "find '{{local_dir}}' -type f | wc -l" """)
['sh', '-c', "find '{{local_dir}}' -type f | wc -l"]
```

making your ansible parameter look like:

```yaml
    command: >-
      sh -ec "find '{{local_dir}}' -type f | wc -l"
```

as always when using jinja2 templates in a shell context, the safer choice is to use [`| quote`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.10/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#manipulating-strings) versus just wrapping your thing in single-quotes and hoping no one uses a single-quote in `local_dir`, although in this case one will need to be extra cautious since it is a shell literal inside a shell literal :-(